# Facebook tab change url without window.location

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

Another question from me.
I'm building a facebook tab. To change from one page to another I'm using AJAX calls, so no page refreshing is done.
Because the page is not reloaded, the url doesn't change, but I'd still like to add something like "#you-are-now-here" at the end of the url, something that is possible in a normal website outside facebook.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Example:

Original url: https://www.facebook.com/pagename/app_appid

The url I want: https://www.facebook.com/pagename/app_appid#you-are-now-here

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate the [HTML5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).  In particular you probably want to be making use of [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).

Comment: Look promising, but not really cross browser compatible since it's HTML5, which is not really supported in older browsers as far as I know.
Is there no other way to do this?